# PHP header() causes internal server error

Tags: php, header

For some reason a call to header() causes an internal server error for me. I'm using PHP5 and use mod_rewrite extensively in this script (if that helps). Here is the code (sort of):

```
<?php 

include 'core/initialize.php'; // Loads the core class (and session manager class)

    if($_GET['reset'] == 'true')
    {
         $core->Session->Visits = 0;
         header('Location', 'index.html');
         # header('X-Test', 'wtf'); // causes the error too :(
    }
    if(isset($core->Session->Visits)) $core->Session->Vists += 1;
    else $core->Session->Visits = 0;
    echo "Previous Visits: {$core->Session->Visits} (<a href='index.html?reset=true'>Reset</a>)";
?>
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Start up the rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ navigator.php?nav=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using this :

```
header('Location', 'index.html');
```

It is not the way [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be used : the second parameter should be a boolean.

ANd the first one should be the header name + value.

So, in your case, something like this :

```
header('Location: index.html');
```

Only one parameter ; and name + ':' + value **:-)**

There is an example in the documentation :

> The second special case is the
>   "Location:" header. 
>   Not only does it
>   send this header back to the browser,
>   but it also returns a REDIRECT (302)
>   status code to the browser unless some
>   3xx status code has already been set.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

As a sidenote, if I remember correctly, you should use a FULL absolute URL when using the `Location` header ; I know using relative URL works in (almost ?) all browsers, but it is not valid, when reading the HTTP RFC, if I recall correctly.

---

As a second sidenote *(yes, the answer has already been accepted, but maybe it'll be useful anyway, for next time :-) )* : that "INternal Server Error" might indicate your PHP script encountered some kind of error.

In that case, you should check the `error_log`'s file...

...Or activate [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to facilitate things -- at least on your development machine.